# C11 compiler for Windows

Tags: windows, c, compiler

I want to know what C11 compilers exist for Windows.

Even better if whatever libraries they use support native C11 threads (ie: not some hacked stuff on top of pthreads).

Comment: native C knows NOTHING about threads.  However, certain libraries do implement threads.  The preferred library to use is `libpthread.so`  which is included in the link statement via `-lpthread` and implements the `posix` thread functions.

Comment: @user3629249, C11 does have threads support. Look here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf
Of course, threads.h implementation depends on a platform or it is a wrapper around platform-specific library.

Comment: Must this complier be free, or do you have abudget?

Comment: @tysonite,  That section (page 386) is a reference to an available/standard library, not part of the C language, but expected to be implemented with the language.

Answer (score -1):

there are a number of 'compilers' for C on windows.

Most are just a front end (GUI) for the `gcc` compiler

Comment: Can you list them? Can you justify that? And, since you say "most", then any which is not included in "most" would be an answer ...

Comment: Neither *I* nor anyone else would have a complete list of compilers.  So the answer can only be in 'generalities'.

Comment: I have used, at least, 20 different compilers that ran on windows (many were cross compilers for other CPUs/Microcontrollers/Microprocessors.)